# Having issues loading firefox browser using selenium on python. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I am having issues loading Firefox browser through Selenium on python.

The code being executed is below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService

service = FirefoxService(executable_path="./geckodriver",)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)
browser.get('http://selenium.dev/')
```

The environments are as follow:

1. Processor :AMD® Ryzen 9 5900hx with radeon graphics × 10
2. OS: Ubuntu 22.04 64 bit - Gnome 42.5
3. Installed Firefox 107.0.1 64 bit via Snap
4. Geckodriver v0.32.0-linux64
5. Selenium version 4.7.2 [installed by Poetry 1.2.2]
6. Python version 3.11.0
7. webdriver-manager library v3.85 [installed by Poetry]

The error stack on executing the command are as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/userhere/source_code/scraper/selenium_main.py", line 7, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)
  File "/home/userhere/source_code/scraper/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 197, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options, keep_alive=True)
  File "/home/userhere/source_code/scraper/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 288, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/userhere/source_code/scraper/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 381, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/userhere/source_code/scraper/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 444, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/userhere/source_code/scraper/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 127
```

Looking into the `geckodriver.log`, the following is logged.

```
1670579048409   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/snap/firefox/current/firefox.launcher" "--marionette" "--remote-debugging-port" "39445" "--remote-allow-hosts" "localhost" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofilerrtoxk"
/snap/firefox/current/firefox.launcher: 46: exec: /snap/pycharm-community/310/usr/lib/firefox/firefox: not found
```

I am able to run Firefox natively, have ensured that the `geckodriver` is executable and running the `geckodriver` via terminal runs and awaits for requests over provided port.

I have tried different versions of `geckodriver` and updated the firefox.

I have also tried using the webdriver-manager to setup environment [code below].

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

service = FirefoxService(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)
```

Executing the code results in the following error trace.

```
[WDM] - Downloading: 19.0kB [00:00, 10.5MB/s]                   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/userhere/source_code/scraper/selenium_main.py", line 8, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)
  File "/home/userhere/source_code/scraper/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 197, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options, keep_alive=True)
  File "/home/userhere/source_code/scraper/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 288, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/userhere/source_code/scraper/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 381, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/userhere/source_code/scraper/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 444, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/userhere/source_code/scraper/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 127
```

Comment: Are you trying to run Selenium on PC or on server computer without a real monitor?

Comment: Nope. The Pc is connected to a monitor. @Prophet

Comment: Are you sure the version of webdriver is compatible to the version of the browser?

Comment: Unsure about that. It wasn't working before I updated everything to the latest version; nor after. I have tried looking for the compatibility list between firefox, geckodriver and selenium but have not been able to find the compatibility list in selenium's website.

I just opted to using the latest version of firefox using snap update, selenium using poetry and gecko on firefox website.

Comment: I see. Please check that since this can be the issue here. I'm not totally sure what actually causes your problem, but this can be one of these.

Comment: There was a bug: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/11414 and some nice guy posted workaround

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure, but this can be caused by incompatibility between your Firefox browser version and the Geckodriver webdriver version.

Comment: Found a link for compatibility.
https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html

```
Installed Firefox 107.0.1 64 bit via Snap
Geckodriver v0.32.0-linux64
Selenium version 4.7.2 [installed by Poetry 1.2.2]
Python version 3.11.0
```

The versions should be compatible.

Comment: I see. I will leave this answer since this may be useful for future users with similar error and in case I will have more ideas what could cause your issue I will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to prove it yet, but perhaps you could try obtaining the driver installer for Firefox in a similar manner as you would for Chrome. Instead of using ChromeService().install(), consider using FirefoxService() for Firefox.